# Windows 10 UWP - Capability: Internet (Client & Server) option error during store upload

Tags: uwp

During store app generation, there is need to check the Capability: Internet (Client & Server) option in the Capabilities and also we must set WinRT Access as ‘ALL’ in the Content URIs tab in the project manifest file.
Without enabling Internet (Client & Server) option in the Capabilities, the mobile app login is getting failed when tested.

But we got failed certification from Microsoft Store during submission process as mentioning below:
•   Error Found: The app manifest test detected the following errors:
o   The Application cannot include an ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly' WindowsRuntimeAccess while any of the following capabilities are enabled: enterpriseAuthentication, sharedUserCertificates, musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary, removableStorage, documentLibrary, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer.
•   Impact if not fixed: Apps that violate the Microsoft Store certification requirements can’t be submitted to the Microsoft Store.

So we please need support on how to upload the app into Microsoft Store as LOB by enabling above features

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Do you build a UWP app via Javascript? Which framework is used?

Comment: Cordova framework is used to build UWP app

Comment: Cordova mentioned this [problem](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/windows/index.html#effect-of-remote-mode-on-capabilities), the description is known, you can refer to its documentation to find a solution in the Cordova community

Comment: We have already checked Cordova. It was mentioned that the network-related restrictions must be worked around by either using an API.
But, there was no API mentioned and existing network related API will only provide network connection state which is not helpful in this case.